# Minimized distance from the origin to the intersection of $xy=6, 7x+24z=0$

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

I have ended up with the $5$ equations of $x,y$ and $a$ and $b$. However I'm stuck with the algebra and cannot proceed. Would be grateful if someone could point me to how to solve these.

Here are the equations:

$2x+7a+yb=0$

$2y+bx=0$

$2z+24a=0$

$7x+24z=0$

$xy=6$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

It is a lot easier to solve this in just one variable.

You must minimise $\frac{36}{x^2}+\frac{625}{576}x^2$. Therefore $$\frac{625}{288}x^4-72=0$$.

So $x=2.4,y=2.5,z=-0.7$.

Comment: +1 I got distracted in the middle of doing this.Since it is essentially the same as yours (albeit done independently) and you got there first, I have deleted mine, but it is encouraging that we end up with essentially the same answer!

Comment: Thanks - jolly decent of you!

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM $$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\sqrt{x^2+\frac{36}{x^2}+\frac{49x^2}{576}}=\sqrt{\frac{625x^2}{576}+\frac{36}{x^2}}\geq\sqrt{2\sqrt{\frac{625x^2}{576}\cdot\frac{36}{x^2}}}=\frac{5}{\sqrt2}.$$
The equality occurs for $$\frac{625x^2}{576}=\frac{36}{x^2}$$ or for example, for
$$(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{12}{5},\frac{5}{2},-\frac{7}{10}\right),$$ which says that we got a minimal value.

Answer (score 0):

Let $P=(x,y,z)$ be the point with the minimal distance. The normal vectors to the two given surfaces

$$f(x,y,z)=xy-6,\>\>\>\>\>g(x,y,z)=7x+24z$$

are

$$n_f =(f_x,f_y,f_z)=(y,x,0),\>\>\>\>\>n_g=(g_x,g_y,g_z)=(7,0,24)$$

The tangent vector at the intersection of the two surfaces is then $n_f\times n_g = (24x,-24y,-7x)$, which is perpendicular to P. Then, we have

$$P\cdot(n_f\times n_g)=0$$
or,

$$24x^2-24y^2-7xz=0$$

Along with $xy=6,\> 7x+24z=0$, solve for the coordinates of the point P to get

$$x^2=\frac{144}{25},\>\>\>\>\>\>y^2=\frac{25}4,\>\>\>\>\>z^2=\frac{49}{100}$$

Thus, the minimum distance is 
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=\frac5{\sqrt2}$$